# Mongoose: Null on nested property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, null, mongoose

I'm not sure if this is correct, but IMO should output TRUE while it outputs FALSE.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var NestedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     nestedProperty: {
         nestedValue: String
     }
}); 

var Nested = mongoose.model('Nested', NestedSchema);

var instance = new Nested();

instance.nestedProperty = null;

console.log(instance.nestedProperty == null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is stored as (kind of) a string.

```
    console.log(instance.nestedProperty == "null"); // true
    console.log(typeof instance.nestedProperty  === "string"); // false
```

Comment: Ok. But this is truly anoying for checks/assertions/... could it be considered a bug?

Comment: It is indeed annoying. It is quite the same as check against _"undefined"_ instead of _undefined_. I'd say you could consider it as a bug. However, since the _nestedProperty_ is of type _string_ there maybe is some explanation in it. It would be worth testing if none _string_ types convert _null_ to something _string_ like, too.